# How to declare a struct where only some members can use a value from another struct?

Tags: struct, rust, default-value

Rust has a useful feature where you can use an existing struct and only override some of its members. For example, a value of the following struct

```
struct SomeTool {
    pub unique_id: String,
    pub poll: Option<fn(&Context) -> bool>,
    pub exec: Option<fn(&mut Context) -> ToolResult>,
    pub modal: Option<fn(&mut Context) -> ToolResult>,
    pub ui: Option<fn(&mut UIPanel)>,
}
```

can be initialized by passing in a struct instance (e.g. `SomeTool::default()`):

```
new_tool = SomeTool {
    unique_id: "tool.foobar".to_string(),
    exec: Some(foobar_exec)
    .. SomeTool::default()
};
```

I want to be able to declare `SomeTool` without having to explicitly list every callback (adding new callbacks in the future may lead to many additions of `None` all over a codebase).

This works well, but now I could accidentally leave out `unique_id` for some other initialization, and it would use whatever is in the `default`.

Is there a way to describe a struct that can have some members overridden but not others?

---

Note that the real world use-case has more members than this (making the chance of accidents higher), just simplified for the question.

Answer (score 8):

Since your `unique_id` is supposed to be unique, it should not have a `Default` constructor. But if you remove the `Default` impl from a hypothetical `UniqueId` type, then you won't be able to derive `Default` for `SomeTool`.

The currently working solution is to move all fields that don't require a value to a sub-struct and not implement `Default` for `SomeTool`. Thus you'd be able to use `SomeTool` as follows:

```
new_tool = SomeTool {
    unique_id: "tool.foobar".to_string(),
    callbacks: Callbacks {
        exec: Some(foobar_exec),
        .. Callbacks::default()
    }
};
```

There is a hypothetical feature that Rust might get in the future, which allows you to have two structs with the same fields to be the base expression in a struct expression. That feature would allow you to use the sub-struct to initialize all the fields that the sub-struct and `SomeTool` have in common, but not more.